# How to Order a 3 Way Tie?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm working on an app that involves inputting the amount of cards players ended up with, and ordering them in a list. But if theres a 2 or 3 way tie, I want the user to be able to have a menu that lets them select the order of who had the highest card to lowest card, that way I can organize the list. How do I get the user to order them, like what kind of Alert/Popup lets me do that?

Edit: Basically I was asking how to make a picker that lets you arrange multiple items into a specific order but it seems the best thing to do is just to have a stack appear with buttons for each item, where you can click them and go from there to create your order. Hope this helps for anyone in a similar situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that kind of user interaction where they are doing more than just tapping an option (in your case, you want them to order the various cards), I would create your own custom view rather than use an alert or action sheet or similar.

The way you implement will depend on how you want it to look. If you want the view to appear on top of your current view (a bit like an alert does) where it only takes up the space needed for the content) then you can embed in a zStack. If you want it to slide up from the bottom as almost the same size as the full screen then you can use a sheet (sometimes also referred to as a modal).

A little difficult to explain how they look visually - if you google image search “SwiftUI sheet” then you’ll see what I mean (if you aren’t already familiar with them)

**ZStack**
you put your current view in a ZStack then create a new view which goes in the ZStack after it but you wrap it in an if statement so it’s conditionally shown based on a Boolean being true.

E.g.

`if gameTied { ChooseSortOrderView() }`

then when your game finishes - if it’s a tie, you set your Boolean to true and up pops the new view.

You can pass in the tied cards, get the user to sort them via drag and drop, form, picker (whatever you want), submit it. Then set the bool back to false to make the view go away.

**sheet**
The other alternative instead of using a zstack would be sheet so you get a modal view appear. Similar approach but instead of the ZStack, you use a .sheet modifier.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I ended up doing. I made a sheet with buttons appearing asking for you to select the player whos highest card is highest, and whos highest card is lowest along with an update button, which is working great for me

Comment: Great news. Good luck with the rest of your project!